# Why does this error show up accessing the RTF of a RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I have a number of rich text boxes on my application that print data received from a digital modem type device. At times it is necessary to copy a window to another window because some of the text in the RTF window is colored and formatted a certain way I thought the best way was to copy the RTF of the window to the other window. But when I run the program and I attempt to copy the text I get this same error either in run mode r if I break the code and try to manually read the RTF.

```
?Hostform.rtfRX(0).TextRTF

'Hostform.rtfRX(0).TextRTF' threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'
    ClassName: Nothing
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233070
    HelpLink: Nothing
    InnerException: Nothing
    MemberName: Nothing
    Message: "Public member 'TextRTF' on type 'RichTextBox' not found."
    Signature: Nothing
    Source: "Microsoft.VisualBasic"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& MemberName, Boolean ReportErrors)" & vbCrLf & "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)" & vbCrLf & "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)"
    TargetSite: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] GetMembers(System.String ByRef, Boolean)}
```

The same error is shown it I use .RTF or .TextRTF
I do not understand why the RTF can't be found when I'm using a Rich Text Box. I'm using a WinForm and made sure the correct type of RTF is being used.

Is there something special I need to turn on the RTF output?

Comment: The .Net RichTextBox control does not have a `TextRTF` property.

Comment: I have also tried just .rtf and it throws the same error...

Comment: `Rtf` is a valid property.  Your post just doesn't contain enough information to help you.

Comment: That `?` seems to be in the wrong place...

Comment: How did you get that specific output? I thought you must be using the Immediate window but I get different output even if I do use a member that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that what you have done is accessed your `RichTextBox` via an `Object` reference with `Option Strict Off`. That's bad to start with. You should have `Option Strict On` pretty much all the time and write your code accordingly. I added a `RichTextBox` to my form and accessed it directly via the generated field in the Immediate window and I got this result:

```
?RichTextBox1.Rtf
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Segoe UI;}}" & vbCrLf & "{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 " & vbCrLf & "\pard\f0\fs18 Hello\par" & vbCrLf & "World\par" & vbCrLf & "}" & vbCrLf
?RichTextBox1.TextRTF
Nothing
```

I then did this:

```vb
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim x As Object = RichTextBox1
    End Sub

End Class
```

and used that `x` variable in the Immediate window and got this:

```
?x.Rtf
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Segoe UI;}}" & vbCrLf & "{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 " & vbCrLf & "\pard\f0\fs18 Hello\par" & vbCrLf & "World\par" & vbCrLf & "}" & vbCrLf
?x.RTF
"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Segoe UI;}}" & vbCrLf & "{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 " & vbCrLf & "\pard\f0\fs18 Hello\par" & vbCrLf & "World\par" & vbCrLf & "}" & vbCrLf
?x.TextRTF
'x.TextRTF' threw an exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'
    ClassName: Nothing
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233070
    HelpLink: Nothing
    InnerException: Nothing
    MemberName: Nothing
    Message: "Public member 'TextRTF' on type 'RichTextBox' not found."
    Signature: Nothing
    Source: "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetMembers(String& memberName, Boolean reportErrors)" & vbCrLf & "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object instance, Type type, String memberName, Object[] arguments, String[] argumentNames, Type[] typeArguments, Boolean[] copyBack)" & vbCrLf & "   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)"
    TargetSite: {System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] GetMembers(System.String ByRef, Boolean)}
```

You should have `Option Strict On` to start with, so the code you have should not compile. Whether you have to or not, you should be casting that `Object` reference as the actual type of the object, then you can access members of that type directly, without late binding. Using my example:

```
?DirectCast(x, RichTextBox).TextRTF
Nothing
```

Comment: The VB6 RichTextBox had a `TextRTF` property.  Maybe the OP is trying to run a converted to .net version.

Comment: @LarsTech, based on what I saw, the .NET `RichTextBox` must have a private property or field with that name. As you can see, I got `Nothing` when using it on a `RichTextBox` reference, whereas a property that definitely didn't exist produced an error. When using late binding, the error message specifically says that there is no PUBLIC member with that name.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You hit it right on the head I was just looking past the issue and wondering why it was not working.. Thank You..

Comment: `textRtf` is a private Field that's used to store the text while the RichTextBox Control is in a transitional state, i.e., the handle is not created or is being recreated. Should not be used, it could be null when the `Text` property is specified